# Check for upper, lower, digits, symbols, and spaces

Tags: java, boolean

so i got working but i need help with reading and counting punctuation
symbols and to read the spaces in the file. I keep getting zero when it prints. Right now everything prints properly and complies so but like i said the spaces and punctuation symbols arnt reading the file and i cannot figure out why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

public class Lab8{

public static void main(String[]args)throws FileNotFoundException{

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter file name : "); 
            String filename = scan.nextLine(); 

    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(filename)); 

    int upperCount = 0;
   int lowerCount = 0;
   int symbolCount = 0;
   int digitCount = 0;
   int spaceCount = 0;



      while(fileScan.hasNext()){
   String name = fileScan.nextLine();


   //Upper Case
   for ( int y = 0; y < filename.length(); y++){
     if ( Character.isUpperCase (filename.charAt(y))){
     upperCount++;
    }//end if
   }//end for

   //Lower Case
   for ( int x = 0; x < filename.length(); x++){
     if ( Character.isLowerCase (filename.charAt(x))){
     lowerCount++;
      }//end if
   }//end for


   //Digits 
   for ( int z = 0; z < filename.length(); z++){
      if ( Character.isDigit(filename.charAt(z))){
      digitCount++;
      }//end if
   }//end for

   //Punctuation Symbols   
    if(filename == "(" + ")" + "," + "." + "!" + "?") {
      symbolCount++;

      }//end if

    //spaces
   for ( int i = 0; i < filename.length(); i++){
      if ( Character.isWhitespace(filename.charAt(i))){
      spaceCount++;
      }//end if
   }//end for


   }//end while
   System.out.println( "Uppercase Letters : " + upperCount );
   System.out.println( "Lowercase Letters : " + lowerCount );
   System.out.println( "Number of Digits : " + digitCount );
   System.out.println( "Punctuation Symbols : " + symbolCount );  
   System.out.println( "Number of Spaces : " + spaceCount );

}//end main
}//end class
```

>

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Iterate the characters of the string, then call one or more of the [`isXxx(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#i26) methods of the [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class to determine the character type. Or call [`getType(char ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType-char-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a question, but you can parse through the text and use `Character.isDigit()`, `Character.isAlphabetic()`, `Character.isLetter()`, `Character.isWhiteSpace()` etc.

ex:

```
    char four = '4';

    if(Character.isDigit(four) {
        System.out.println("The Character is a digit");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The character is not a digit");

    Output:
    The Character is a digit.
```

In your case, you could parse through the whole file and then if it is what you are looking for, then you  can just add to the upperCount, lowerCount, digitCount, or spaceCount, etc.

Comment: In the Character wrapper class, there is also Character.isLowerCase(), or Character.isUpperCase(), that would help you with the upper and lower case.

Comment: *"The Character is a number"* No, the character is a *digit*. `123` is a *number*, consisting of 3 *digits*. That's why the method is called `isDigit`.

Comment: You could also look at all of the options for the Character class here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Andreas.I fixed the example.